# How to mock a method or function to return an expected error

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Trying to learn how to write better tests with Jest/Typescript. I would like to ensure that I can test for an error.

I can create mocked method that will return an expected array of data, however testing for errors is proving difficult.

```
//program.ts
const listStacks = async (cf: CloudFormation): Promise<StackSummaries> => {
  try {
        const result = await cf.listStacks().promise();
        if (result.StackSummaries) {
          return result.StackSummaries;
        }
        return [];
  } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e;  
  }
```

Here is my test below, note i've tried returning a new Error instead of a throw but that doesn't appear to work either.

```
//program.test.js
it('handles errors gracefully', async () => { 
    expect.assertions(1);
    const cfMock = {
        listStacks: (): any => ({
            promise: async () => {
                    throw new Error('ohh NOO!');             
            }
        })
    }
    expect(() => listStacks(cfMock as CloudFormation)).toThrow();
```

Jest returns this:

```
expect(received).toThrow()

Received function did not throw .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listStacks` is an `async` function.

`async` functions [return the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value):

> A `Promise` which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.

In this case you are providing a mock which causes an uncaught exception to be thrown within the `async` function, so *it will return a `Promise` which will reject with the uncaught exception*.

To verify this behavior change your `expect` line to the following:

```js
await expect(listStacks(cfMock)).rejects.toThrow();  // SUCCESS
```

---

Note that `toThrow` was fixed for promises with [PR 4884](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4884) so if you are using an older version of `Jest` (before 22.0.0) you will need to use something like `toEqual`:

```js
await expect(listStacks(cfMock)).rejects.toEqual(expect.any(Error));  // SUCCESS
```

Comment: I think my program.js is not returning the right type to support the toThrow:


`Matcher error: received value must be a promise

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]`

Comment: @Andrew did you remove the anonymous function from the `expect` statement and just call `listStacks` directly?

Comment: oh how did I not see that syntax!! `expect(listStacks(cfMock as CloudFormation)).rejects.toThrow();` passes now. Thank you!!

Comment: @Andrew you’re welcome, glad to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the `throw` statement inside the operation made in the `try` block. for example:

```
  if(!result.StackSummaries) {
    throw new Error('error message to assert') 
  }
```

The `catch` block will catch any error thrown in the `try` block, so you can mock the return of listStacks to be null so that it falls on that if and throws the error.

Comment: returning an empty array is OK, so I really want to make sure that my catch (e) is working. I was trying to do this by having the listStacks().promise() return an error that would trigger a catch.